# Is this correct

Tags: differences, word-usage

"Now he occasionally felt like working" in a oxford 
 Bookworm

Should  not it be "feels" instead of felt ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "Now he occasionally felt like working" is grammatically correct.

I don't know if it *should* be "felt" because you haven't given enough context, but saying "felt" in that sentence isn't ungrammatical. If the speaker is saying the action of "feeling" took place in the past and is complete, then "felt" is right.  "Feels" is present tense.  "Felt" is past tense.

If you're wondering about the word "now" heading that sentence, understand that it's not being used to say that the action of "feeling" is happening in the present. Again, you haven't provided enough context to know exactly what that sentence is to get across, but operating from an assumption that "felt"--past tense--isn't a mistake, we should surmise that "now" is being properly used to do either of the following:

1. Call draw the listeners attention:

> [now](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/now) - 2. Used, especially in conversation, to draw attention to a particular statement or point in a narrative : ‘*now*, my first impulse *was* to run
>   away’; ‘I don't like Scotch. *Now*, if it *had been* Irish Whiskey you'd
>   offered me.’

2. Express what was current in the past, for example, "The jury was now ready to render its verdict"; or, "This was new.  *Now* he occasionally *felt* like working.  He had never felt like working before."

> [now](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/now) - 1.5 (in a narrative or account of past events) at the time
>   spoken of or referred to : ‘she was nineteen now, and she was alone’

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are correct, your sentence should read,

> Now he occasionally feels like working. [Just be sure to put a period after the word *working*.]

On the other hand, if you were to add a few words to the end of your sentence, as in the following example, you should use the word *felt*.

> Now he occasionally felt like working, but only occasionally, and not full time.

Also, by adding a few words to the beginning of your sentence, you could be equally correct in using the word *feels*.

> In the weeks following his accident he was neither able to work nor did he feel like working, but because of his rapid healing, now he occasionally feels  like working.

I suppose you could also put the adverb *occasionally* at the end of the sentence, though you don't have to for correctness sake.

> Now he felt like working occasionally."